# Beracha priority of Al Hamichya fruits

Tags: blessing, mezonot-beracha, ikkar-tafel

Are the “5 fruits of the land of Israel” automatically ikkar— even without majority— like mezonot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the 5 grains are automatically ikkar, not fruits. [Mishnah Brurah 204 sk 57](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.204.57?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (also see the Shulchan Aruch he is commenting on for some context):

> הרי הוא עיקר - המ"א ושארי האחרונים הסכימו דהוא **דוקא בחמשת מיני דגן** אמרינן דהיכא דבא ליתן טעם אף שהוא מיעוט הוא העיקר וכדלקמן בסימן ר"ח ס"ב **אבל בשארי 
>   מינים אזלינן בתר רובא**