# After-beracha for yogurt and raisins

Tags: blessing, food, ikkar-tafel

Let's say the yogurt is the majority, yet there is a kazayit of raisins. Lav dafka raisins.

Does the yogurt act as ikkar with regards to the after-beracha as well (as stated [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/berachos-over-food-mixtures) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/113388/beracha-priority-of-al-hamichya-fruits))? Is the koach of ikkar regarding *shehakol* over one of the fruits of Israel really that strong?

Answer (score 3):

The Pninei Halacha [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/category/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA/11-%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8-%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A4%D7%9C/#_te01ftnref11_4) says:

> לגבי ברכה אחרונה, בדרך כלל ברכת שני המינים ‘בורא נפשות’. אבל אם יש שם מפירות שבעת המינים, ואכל מכל אחד מהסוגים כ’זית’, אלא שאכלם בתערובת, מחמת הספק יוכל לברך רק על המאכל שממנו הרוב. ואם ירצה לצאת מהספק, יאכל מהמיעוט כ’זית’ בנפרד, וכך יוכל לברך בסוף ‘מעין שלוש’ ו’בורא נפשות’. וראו בהערה הבאה ולעיל י, ג, 4.
>
> Regarding the Bracha Acharona, if there is a mixture (of two types of things), you should make a Borei Nefashot. However, if there is a mixture, and one is one of the Shivat HaMinim, but you eat it in a mixture, because of the doubt, you can only make a Bracha on whatever is the majority. And if you want to rid yourself of the doubt, you should eat a Kezayit on its own, and then you can make both a Birchat Me'ein Shalosh and a Borei Nefashot.